# How to get the stringValue of a Text Field Cell inside a Table View after editing the cell?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a standard Table View with the default settings inside my main nib. I use an Array Controller and Bindings for dealing with the data that the table view should show to the users. I already achieved that the "add" button inserts the new row and sets the first column to editing mode so the users can type their text immediately. My problem is i can't detect when the editing is over and i should save the new values. I couldn't find any delegate method and/or any notification for this purpose. I searched the internet and i couldn't find anything useful. I'm not even sure that i'm doing it right, i didn't add any specific thing, i just use the standard double click editing that the table view offers for each cell.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have everything hooked up with bindings, you shouldn't need to save the data until you exit the program.  When the array controller's add: method is called, the new record is added to the controller's arranged objects, and the array holding your data is also updated. So, you only need to save the array when your app closes.

However, if you wish to save the data after every edit, you can detect the end of the editing with the delegate method controlTextDidEndEditing:. You will get a notification after each column is finished editing (make sure to make the class where you implement this method the delegate of the table view).